# Algebraic independence of `Riemann-Roch' elements

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, elliptic-curves

First of all, I'm not too sure on what terminology should be used in the title: the question deals with the vector spaces $$\mathcal{L(D)}=\{f\colon E\to\mathbb{C} \mid f\text{ is meromorphic}, (f)+D\geqslant0 \}$$
where $E$ is some elliptic curve and $D$ is some divisor on it.
**Bonus question:** *is there a standard name for this vector space? I can't find one in any of my books, or on Wikipedia. I know that it is also called $H^0(E,\mathcal{O}_E(D))$, but this is usually accompanied by a definition involving global sections or suchlike, which is a bit above my level at the moment.*

But my **main question** comes from examining the case when $D=P$ is a point in $E$.

By Riemann-Roch we know that $$\ell(nD)=\begin{cases}1\quad\mbox{if }n=0 ,\\n\quad\mbox{for }n\geqslant1.\end{cases}$$
So $\ell(P)=1$, and so we can pick some $x\in\mathcal{L}(P)$ such that $\mathcal{L}(P)=\langle x\rangle$.
Now $x^2\in\mathcal{L}(2P)$, and then we pick some $y\in\mathcal{L}(2P)$ such that $\mathcal{L}(2P)=\langle x^2, y\rangle$. Finally we do a similar thing to get that $\mathcal{L}(3P)=\langle x^3, xy, z\rangle$.

But this process, however simple, leaves me with a few questions:

1. How can we show that these sets (e.g. $\{x^2,y\}$) are linearly independent, and thus form a basis?
2. <strike>How can we then show that $x,y,z$ are all algebraically independent?</strike> EDIT: How can we show that $x,y$ are algebraically independent? On a problem sheet by Miles Reid he gives the hint

   > Prove that $x^2,y$ defines a 2-to-1 map $E\to\mathbb{P}^1$ so that $x,y$ are algebraically independent. Prove that $y$ has a pole at $P$ of order $2$, and $z$ a pole of order $3$.

   First of all I'm not too sure what exactly he means by the first part, and  I'm not too sure how to apply that fact even if I could prove it. Secondly, what is the second part of the hint getting at?
3. **We know that there is a degree $6$ relation between $x,y,z$, and by a change of variables we can show that it takes a certain form ($z^2=y^3+ax^4y+bx^6$) *provided that* we can show that the relation must involve $y^3$ and $z^2$. How can we show this?**

Guidance and hints would be appreciated as much as, if not more than, full answers!

Comment: Use that $L(P)=\mathbb C\subsetneq L(2P)\subsetneq L(3P)$. (The first equality sign is genuine equality, not only isomorphism.) Any element  in $L(2P)\setminus L(P)$ has a pole of order $2$ at $P$ etc. Also: you can't show 2. because $x,y,z$ are algebraically *dependent*.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ok, but it is true that $x$ and $y$ are algebraically independent though? That's what the hint says, and I assumed that the second bit was driving to show that $x,y,z$ were all algebraically independent. But thinking about it, we know that there is a degree $6$ relation between $x,y,z$, so that's obvious in hindsight!

Comment: Hmm. Don't we have $\ell(1P)=\ell(0P)=1$, so $\mathcal{L}(P)$ is spanned by the constant mapping to $1$? $\mathcal{L}(2P)$ is the smallest space containing a non-constant mapping, call it $x$. Then as $\dim \mathcal{L}(3P)=3$, there is another function $y$, linearly independent from $1$ and $x$, with its only pole of order 3 at $P$. We then see that $x^2$ has a pole of order $4$, $xy$ a poly of order $5$ and both $x^3$ and $y^2$ of order six. Because $\dim \mathcal{L}(6P)=6$, the seven functions $1,x,y,x^2,xy,x^3,y^2$ must be linearly dependent, and this gives us an equation for the curve.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That sounds much like what I've found so far, yes. The only thing I'd say is that the $1\in\mathcal{L}(0P)$ is 'different', in a sense, from the $1\in\mathcal{L}(1P)$, because of the graded ring structure underlying this ($\bigoplus_{n\geqslant0}\mathcal{L}(nP)$), hence why I use $x^n$ as the '1 element' in $\mathcal{L}(nP)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But I think that's just semantics. My main question is: how do we know that this linear dependence equation specifically has non-zero coefficients for the $y^3$ and $z^2$ terms? (or in your notation, $x^3$ and $y^2$)

Comment: Tim: Those two terms are the only ones not in $\mathcal{L}(5P)$. That space is 5-dimensional, and spanned by $1,x,y,x^2,xy$ (those all have different pole orders so they are automatically linearly independent). Therefore any linear dependency relation must involve both of $x^3$ and $y^2$. Or, if you prefer to think about it that way, those two must cancel the pole of order six produced by the other - the lower order poles are useless for that purpose.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think I understand (and see now why you use $1$ rather than $x$), but I'm not too sure about the last part where you explain it in a different way - those two must cancel which pole of order six?

Comment: $x$ has a pole of order 2 at $P$, $y$ has one of order 3, $x^2$ of order $4$, $xy$ of order 5, and both $x^3$ and $y^2$ have a pole of order six. Consider a linear dependency relation such as
$$c_1\cdot1+c_2\cdot x+c_3\cdot y+c_4\cdot x^2+c_5\cdot xy+c_6\cdot x^3+c_7\cdot y^2=0.$$
The r.h.s. has no pole at $P$, so the l.h.s. cannot have one either. Because a pole of lower order cannot cancel one of a higher order either here $c_6=c_7=0$ or they are both non-zero. The former possibility forces all the $c_i$ to zero (their pole orders are distinct), which is useless.